# Plot two files in gnuplot with different timefmt

Tags: gnuplot, datetime-format

I need to plot two data file in the same graph, with gnuplot. The first data file is like:

```
2015-02-10 10.1
2015-02-15 12.1
2015-02-20 16.1
2015-02-25 14.1
...
```

and the second data file is like

```
2015-02-10-10:00 12.5
2015-02-10-15:00 21.4
2015-02-15-12:30 08.3
2015-02-15-22:00 09.3
2015-02-20-08:15 12.8
2015-02-20-17:32 16.7
2015-02-25-07:20 14.0
2015-02-25-21:39 14.5
..
```

To parse the first data file, `timefmt` should be set to `"%Y-%m-%d"` and for the second file it would be `"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"`. However, since both data files should be ploted together, how do I define `timefmt` properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With verrsion 4.6 and earlier you must parse the datetime strings 'manually' with `strptime`:

```
set xdata time
plot 'file1.dat' using (strptime('%Y.%m.%d', strcol(1))):2,\
     'file2.dat' using (strptime('%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M', strcol(1))):2
```

With gnuplot version 5 you can directly give a time format to the `timecolumn` function, so that you can use as much formats as you want:

```
set xdata time
plot 'file1.dat' using (timecolumn(1, '%Y.%m.%.d')):2,\
     'file2.dat' using (timecolumn(1, '%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M')):2
```

In your case the difference between the two variants is marginal, but when the date time spreads over more than one column in the data file, then the latter variant is much more comfortable, since `timecolumn` handles the multiple columns automatically.